# VS 2010 - Code Coverage Results includes the test project itself

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-coverage

I am writing some unit tests for one of my DLL libraries.
The 'Code Coverage Results' pane shows a breakdown of the assemblies covered and tested.

For some strange reason - my **test project itself** appears in the coverage results ! (at approx. 90% covered).

This seems stupid... what's the deal with this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the percentage is so high is that projects for code coverage are instrumented to keep track of which lines are hit by a test run, since you are running the tests from this project, almost all lines of code in the project will be run.

You can choose which projects/DLLs to collect Coverage statistics on in the Test Settings.

So if you don't need to capture stats on the test project (which you shouldn't really), you can simply remove this project from the settings you're using for coverage.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182534.aspx (steps 5 - 7 in particular) for more details.